# pandas dataframe with just one column and hundreds of rows having a dictionary withh same keys but different values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file that has just one column with hundreds of rows. The column pattern is the same as that of a python dictionary, I want to convert it to multiple columns based on its keys. the column name is 0.

```
0 = [{'author': 'steve', 'age': '19', 'job': 'contractor'}, {'author': 'paul', 'age': '24', 'job': 'service'}]
```

What I want:

```
author   age   job
steve    19    contractor
paul     24    service
```

tell me the possible ways in python pandas data frame to convert it into multiple columns and export it into an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize semi-structured JSON data into a flat table.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import json_normalize

data = {
  0 : [{'author': 'steve', 'age': '19', 'job': 'contractor'}, {'author': 'paul', 'age': '24', 'job': 'service'}]
}

df2 = json_normalize(data[0])
print(df2)

#Save file in excel
df2.to_excel("path")
#df2.to_excel("C:\file.xlsx")
```